# Docker log in command does not work

Tags: docker, boot2docker, dockerfile, dockerhub, docker-registry

I have installed boot2docker on on my windows machine and have created a repository on docker hub. I am trying to log in with the following command in the linux shell:

```
docker login --username=myusername --password=mypassword --email=myemail@gmail.com
```

But I am getting this in the shell:

[image]

The password field appears asking me to enter my password, but when I do and press enter, nothing happens.

Ideas?

Comment: I have edited [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34850452/6309): PR 19891 should fix the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update February 2016

[PR 19891 "Enable cross-platforms login to Registry"](https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/19891) is supposed to fixed the issue

> Use a daemon-defined Registry URL for docker login.
>
> This allows a Windows client interacting with a Linux daemon to properly use the default Registry endpoint instead of the Windows specific one.

It is in [commit 19eaa71](https://github.com/docker/docker/commit/19eaa71e85f9563e1428347fa9a91c8aa71f1f6d) (maybe for docker 1.10?)

---

[tyagian](https://github.com/tyagian) reports the [following solution](http://networkengg.com/docker-login-failed-on-windows-403-forbidden-error/) in [issue 18019](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/18019#issuecomment-172452301):

> Open the config json file: `C:\Users\Username\.docker\config.json`
>
> It will look like this:

```
{
  "auths": {
    "https://index.docker.io/v1/": {
      "auth": "<hash value>",
      "email": "<email-address>"
    }
  }
}
```

Change it to:

```
{
  "auths": {
    "https://index.docker.io/v1/": {
      "auth": "<hash value>",
      "email": "<email-d>"
    },
    "https://registry-win-tp3.docker.io/v1/": {
      "auth": "<hash value>",
      "email": "<email-address>"
    }
  }
}
```

> and then try again:

```
$ docker push username/image-name
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if the file `config.json` exists. Usually this file is under `~/.docker/` directory.

try:

`cat ~/.docker/config.json`

Comment: It does not exist. Now what do I do?

Comment: Can you pull a public image? Also, could you try ```docker version``` command and write here the response?

Comment: $ docker version
Client version: 1.7.1
Client API version: 1.19
Go version (client): go1.4.2
Git commit (client): 786b29d
OS/Arch (client): windows/amd64
Server version: 1.7.1
Server API version: 1.19
Go version (server): go1.4.2
Git commit (server): 786b29d
OS/Arch (server): linux/amd64

Comment: I can pull a public image because I was able to pull the hello-world example in the docker tutorial on the official website and also the whalesay cowsay image

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is a known issue:

- https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/18019
- https://github.com/docker/hub-feedback/issues/473

The second link provides a workaround, but it's not working for me.